# Warning after deploy in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I hope someone could help me to solve this issue. I'm quite new with React and Firebase, after running a build inside the project I deployed it on Firebase, but I receive this warning. I really don't understand what I could do. Thanks in advance.

Welcome
Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

[image]

Comment: It's not a warning.  You just deployed the default content provided by the Firebase CLI instead of providing your own content.  The CLI publishes files in the hosting "public" folder by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DougStevenson said, you have deployed the default content.

Since this is a React app, you want to do a `build` (typically `npm run build`) of your React project and then deploy the build output (typically in a folder named `build` or `dist`).  You can either change the build output location by modifying your project's build configuration, or you can modify the `hosting.public` property in `firebase.json` so that it points to the build output folder.

For example, you might set in `firebase.json`:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  },
  .................
}
```

Comment: yep the problem was about the location of the build folder, thank you!